# How to connect a live database situated in cpanel to powerbi

Tags: powerbi

I have a live database in **cpanel hosted in phpmyadmin**. I was able to setup the database in **MySql Workbench** but when i am trying to connect it to **powerbi** it showing error like below:
[image]

How can i connect this this live database to powerbi for analysis and other purpose? What am i doing wrong and what should i do to do it correctly? Any suggestion will be helpful .TA

Comment: Is this from Power BI Desktop? Can you connect using a standard MySQL client? We don't know what you're doing wrong because you haven't explained in detail what you are actually doing. Have you granted external access as per the "via CPanel" section in this doc (which may be out of date) https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/how-to-remotely-connect-to-the-mysql-database

Comment: yes this is from Power BI Desktop. I was able to connect my database to MySql Workbench. I have granted external access. Can you tell what is the next step to connect it to powerbi? I connected it to MySql Workbech through "Standard TCP/IP over SSH" method

Comment: It would help if you described how you set it up in MySQL Workbench and how you set it up in Power BI then we could compare. BTW I have never connected to MySQL before so I don't have an immediate answer but I can help troublehsoot